# How to detect CPU load from css?

Tags: css, performance, google-chrome-devtools

Recently on a current project, I've migrated less-variables to CSS-vars. After this changes, chrome dev tools work slowly, not sure that the changes are the reason for the performance issue. But it's the only significant change during the last few days.

I was looking for information about the topic but found nothing valuable.

**Question: how to detect if that's the reason? How to measure load from stylesheet?**

P.S. information from chrome audit

https://monosnap.com/file/hIfvarDZayvrrHCYNFW1RCy8QRxm8x

https://monosnap.com/file/GCAgo5wj60mLTbgG5l7iHrbEpSd2eM

I see the issue on FMP, but it doesn't answer the question

Comment: Try Chrome Audits and paste your results.

Comment: @FabioManzano post updated